# What can I do with the recovered files on an external drive after testdisk finds them?

Tags: data-recovery, external-hdd, testdisk

I used testdisk to locate missing or deleted files on an external hard drive and it found them. I then used "c" to copy the files but could not paste them to desktop or anywhere and could not change the directory in the testdrive app to paste them anywhere... What can I do with the files after testdisk finds them?
What is the situation if I open testdisk on my laptop but use it for an external hard drive? I have a 1 TB Onedrive account but see that it doesn't work with ubuntu except to upload from online. I apologize but I am not a programmer. Any suggestions on where I can put the recovered files from the external hard drive when I recover them with testdisk and then upload them to onedrive or put them back on the external hard drive? Thank you again – Chris Crabtree